# Как заставить демон перезагрузить файлы конфигурации и библиотеку после обновления пакета плагина

Tags: linux, debian

Мой deb-пакет с плагином для Lighttpd содержит динамически загружаемый файл `usr/lib/lighttpd/mod_pdujson.so` и конфигурационный файл `etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/10-pdujson.conf`. Сам проект находится на [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/sercxjo/pducontrol).

В принципе всё работает, кроме того, что после установки или обновления пакета приходится вручную давать команду lighttpd перезагрузить конфигурацию и плагины:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lighttpd reload
```

Как сделать, чтобы это происходило автоматически после установки или обновления пакета?

Comment: 1. http://askubuntu.com/q/492871/416190 2. https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.ru.html#maintscripts 3. https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html 4. https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/ch06.ru.html#bpp-debian-maint-scripts

Comment: а установку или обновление вы как делаете - руками, по крону, ещё как-нибудь?

Comment: @NickVolynkin пока руками через `dpkg -i` или `apt-get install/upgrade`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

основываясь на информации и рекомендациях:

- [Руководство начинающего разработчика Debian - 5.19. Файлы {pre|post}{inst|rm}](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.ru.html#maintscripts)
- [Debian Policy Manual - Chapter 6 - Package maintainer scripts and installation procedure](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html)
- [Справочник разработчика Debian - 6.4. Лучшие практики для сценариев сопровождающих](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/ch06.ru.html#bpp-debian-maint-scripts)
- [What is the right way to restart dependent services while package installation?](https://askubuntu.com/q/492871/416190)

и содержимом актуальных скриптов (в `/var/lib/dpkg/info`), вам надо добавить (как минимум) послеустановочный скрипт, который должен располагаться в файле вида `debian/имя-собираемого-пакета.postinst` и содержать примерно следующее:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

case "$1" in
  configure)
    invoke-rc.d lighttpd reload >/dev/null || true
    ;;
  *)
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Да, как я понял, `invoke-rc.d` - единственное что нужно, `service` всё равно им же и вызывается, а прямой вызов из `/etc/init.d/` debhelper сам не делает когда `пакет.init.d` обрабатывает.
Однако, после `invoke-rc.d lighttpd reload` не работают другие команды с этим сервисом, баг какой-то, придётся наверно на `force-reload` заменить

Comment: @sercxjo force-reload это как? Может сразу restart?

Comment: @sercxjo, а откуда вообще взялся reload? учитывая, что подменяется, насколько я понял, не только конфигурация, лучше, вероятно, использовать банальный restart.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, в старт-стоповых скриптах может быть реализовано много разных команд. это несложно, добавить ещё пунктов в операторе case.

Comment: Странно, но reload и force-reload в /etc/init.d/lighttpd в одном кейсе стоят, а работают по-разному. По сути все делают restart, но reload "забывает" ключ -D судя по `ps -ax`

Comment: @NickVolynkin я думал вначале, что reload не перезапускает процесс, а так да, может быть restart лучше